# How to speed up a query with nested loops

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I have this query that works but it is slow

```
SELECT
  ID_NODE,
  -- this case slows down the query!!!
  CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT MV.ID_CHILD FROM MYVIEW MV INNER JOIN MYTABLE1 MT1 ON MT1.ID_NODE = MV.ID_CHILD WHERE MV.ID_PARENT = CA.ID_NODE AND ID_FATHER IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILDREN,
  OTHER_FIELDS
FROM
  MYTABLE2
```

**Update**: After the first answer I realized my sample was not perfect, so i modified it doign 2 changes (`CA` to `MT1`, and writing `MT1.ID_FATHER` isntead of `ID_FATHER`)

```
  SELECT
  ID_NODE,
  -- this case slows down the query!!!
  CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT MV.ID_CHILD FROM MYVIEW MV INNER JOIN MYTABLE1 MT1 ON MT1.ID_NODE = MV.ID_CHILD WHERE MV.ID_PARENT = MT2.ID_NODE AND MT1.ID_FATHER IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILDREN,
  OTHER_FIELDS
FROM
  MYTABLE2
```

**End of update**

Basically I want a `'y'/'n'` result about "does this node have a child?

In execution plan i see only one warning that is:

> Nested Loop (inner Join)) 43%

Could you please suggest an improvement to the query?

As exterme solution i can store in the table the `HAVE_CHILDREN` value as a new field, but i don't like this because it is an "highway to bugs".

Note for Bounty:

I post here the original tables, view  (made with CREATE statements) and query to help provide a reply:

```
--This is MYTABLE1

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI](
    [ID_PROG_OPERAZIONE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_CESPITE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_TIPO_OPERAZIONE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SEQUENZA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_RESPONSABILE] [int] NULL,
    [DATA_SCADENZA] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATA_ULTIMA] [datetime] NULL,
    [ID_TIPO_FREQUENZA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FREQUENZA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NOTIFICA_SCADENZA] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [COSTO_FISSO] [numeric](19, 4) NOT NULL,
    [NOTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ID_CONTO_FORNITORE] [int] NULL,
    [ID_ESECUTORE] [int] NULL,
    [GIORNI_INTERVENTO_PREVISTI] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RIPETIZIONE] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [RIPETIZIONE_CONTINUA] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [RIPETI_FINO_A] [datetime] NULL,
    [SOSPESO] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ORE_LAVORO_PREVISTE] [decimal](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DESCR_TITOLO_OPERAZIONE] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ID_TEMPLATE] [int] NULL,
    [TEMPLATE] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [ID_PARENT_TEMPLATE_REMOTE] [int] NULL,
    [ATTIVO] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_PARENT_TEMPLATE] [int] NULL,
    [NOTIFY_RESPONSIBLE] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_EXECUTOR] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_OTHERS] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_INADVANCE] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_ADVANCE_DAYS] [int] NULL,
    [NOTIFY_ONEXECUTION] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_ONCLOSE] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [ID_UTENTE_INS] [int] NULL,
    [DATA_INS] [datetime] NULL,
    [ID_UTENTE_ULT_MOD] [int] NULL,
    [DATA_ULTIMA_MOD] [datetime] NULL,
    [STATO_CKL] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TAGAPPSYNC] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [IS_FATHER] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_FATHER] [int] NULL,
    [NOTIFY_DELAYS] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [NOTIFY_DELAYS_DAYS] [int] NULL,
    [NOTIFY_INS_USER] [nchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_PROG_OPERAZIONE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

--This is MYTABLE2

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CES_ANAGRAFICA](
    [ID_CESPITE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_CESPITE_PADRE] [int] NULL,
    [COD_CESPITE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DESCR_CESPITE] [nvarchar](120) NOT NULL,
    [IMMATERIALE] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DATA_ACQUISTO] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATA_ENTRATA_FUNZIONE] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATA_DISMISSIONE] [datetime] NULL,
    [BENE_USATO] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_UBICAZIONE] [int] NULL,
    [NRO_IDENTIFICAZIONE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MARCA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MODELLO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MARCATURA_CE] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [ANNO_COSTRUZIONE] [int] NULL,
    [MATRICOLA_COSTRUTTORE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [COSTRUTTORE] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [ID_CONTO_FORNITORE] [int] NULL,
    [NOTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ID_TIPO_CESPITE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_STATO_CESPITE] [int] NULL,
    [ID_CONTO_PROPRIETA] [int] NULL,
    [ID_RESPONSABILE] [int] NULL,
    [DATA_SCAD_GARANZIA] [datetime] NULL,
    [CAMPO_MISURA] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [CRITERI_ACC] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [RISOLUZIONE] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [ID_USO_STRUMENTO] [int] NULL,
    [ID_REFERENTE] [int] NULL,
    [FOTO] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [PROF_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_TEMPLATE] [int] NULL,
    [TEMPLATE] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [ID_PARENT_TEMPLATE_REMOTE] [int] NULL,
    [ID_PARENT_TEMPLATE] [int] NULL,
    [ISLOCKED] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [TAGAPPSYNC] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [TAGAPPDOCSYNC] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CES_ANAGRAFICA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_CESPITE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

--This is MYVIEW

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_CESPITE_TREE] AS
--BEGIN
    WITH    q AS
            (
            SELECT  ID_CESPITE , ID_CESPITE AS ID_CESPITE_ANCESTOR
            FROM    CES_ANAGRAFICA c
            JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE ctc ON ctc.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR = c.ID_TIPO_CESPITE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  c.ID_CESPITE, q.ID_CESPITE_ANCESTOR 
            FROM    q
            JOIN    CES_ANAGRAFICA c 
            ON      c.ID_CESPITE_PADRE = q.ID_CESPITE
            JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE ctc ON ctc.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR = c.ID_TIPO_CESPITE
            ) 
    select ID_CESPITE AS ID_CHILD, ID_CESPITE_ANCESTOR AS ID_PARENT from q

GO

-- So my original query was this:

SELECT
  CA.ID_CESPITE,CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT VCA.ID_CHILD FROM V_CESPITE_TREE VCA INNER JOIN MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO ON MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD WHERE VCA.ID_PARENT = CA.ID_CESPITE AND ID_FATHER IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILD_PRG,
  CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE
  <Other Fields>

FROM
  CES_ANAGRAFICA CA LEFT OUTER JOIN
  CES_PERMESSI CP ON ((CA.ID_CESPITE = CP.ID_CESPITE)) INNER JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE CTCS ON CA.ID_TIPO_CESPITE = CTCS.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR LEFT OUTER JOIN
  V_UTENTI_DIPENDENTI VUD ON CA.ID_RESPONSABILE = VUD.ID_DIPENDENTE
```

Comment: What is the referenced table with prefix CA?

Comment: How is nested query relates on `mytable2`?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what exactly you want to see in the solution?

Comment: Can you tell how many rows are there in each table?

Comment: I think you're missing some tables that are referenced. An indicative row-count would be helpful too indeed. I assume that `MT2` is an alias for `MYTABLE2` ? Also, does this have to be a single-query solution or can we use intermediate temporary tables and/or table-variables ?

Comment: The schema is still missing a table CES_TIPI_RESPITE. Also I put in some bogus data and getting recursion limit reached with your code. If you can post the schema and test data in an SqlFiddle (sqlfiddle.com) as a working example, then I can update my CTE code to work for you.

Comment: Got the recursion thing resolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE ; it will load your inner join once and then cache it.

Note I don't know where the CA.ID_NODE comes from as you didn't explain that. 
Also your inner query joins to MyTable1, but you're not relating MyTable2 and the subquery.

Given off what you've provided, the pseudo-code should be something like this:
(If you update your question with pertinent info I'll update this answer to reflect it).

**Update:**

Here's an updated version based on your schema update and some sample data. I confirmed this no longer causes duplicates. The real question is for you to check it and make sure it increases the performance, aka lowers execution time.

```
; with hasChildCte(ID_CESPITE, ID_PARENT)
As (
        SELECT VCA.ID_CHILD,
            vca.ID_PARENT
        FROM V_CESPITE_TREE VCA 
          INNER JOIN MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO 
            ON MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD 
        WHERE ID_FATHER 
            IS NOT NULL
)

Select
    CA.ID_CESPITE,
    Case 
        When Exists (
            Select ID_PARENT 
            From hasChildCte cte 
        Where cte.ID_PARENT = ca.ID_CESPITE
        ) Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
    End As HAVE_CHILDREN,
    CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE
From CES_ANAGRAFICA CA
```

Note also if you don't have indexes on all of the joined columns, it would be a good move to put those in. This will help to speed up the query further especially if you're working with a large amount of data.

**Update 2**

The comment about the CTE executing more than once got me thinking, and it is apparently up to SQL server to decide to cache a CTE or not, rather than always caching. In many cases CTE will execute only once, but other times it's similar to a view in SQL server and doesn't get cached.

Consequently, I've modified the code to use a `table variable` instead. I don't have enough test data to see which performs better or faster, though.

Try this and see if it yields a faster query execution time. Note also regardless of which method of refactoring and performance improvement you choose, it's a good idea to have your database properly setup with indexes on the columns you are using in JOIN's. This increases query execution time significantly, at the slight cost on inserts of the index having to be updated.

The updated, non-CTE, code, using a table variable instead:

```
Declare @HasChildren table (ID_CESPITE int, ID_PARENT int)

Insert into @HasChildren
Select VCA.ID_CHILD,
    vca.ID_PARENT
From V_CESPITE_TREE VCA 
    Inner Join MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO 
    On MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD 
Where ID_FATHER 
    Is Not Null

Select
    CA.ID_CESPITE,
    Case 
        When Exists (
            Select ID_PARENT 
            From @HasChildren c
        Where c.ID_PARENT = ca.ID_CESPITE
        ) Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
    End As HAVE_CHILDREN,
    CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE
From CES_ANAGRAFICA CA
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, your suggstion is not working because of my not perfect example, as you pointed out. I modified it and you find the modified version just below the original one.

Comment: @user193655 I updated the answer to reflect your new info, try it. If it's still difficult to make it work, you'll need to post the schema of MyTable1, MyTable2, and MyView

Comment: Thanks again, this time i can at least try it, anyway i still see a difference (50 more records in your query than in my original one). I will post the original table structures (so from now on i refer to original names and not "Mocked up ones). I will also start a bounty to award you the reputation you deserve. Unfortunately I am newbee to CTEs so i cannot tell much.

Comment: CTE's will not execute once but will be executed for every row in the outer query.

Comment: Fantastic! Query results are now really the same. +500 to you!

Comment: Awesome, just curious what was the execution time savings for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  CA.ID_CESPITE,
  CASE WHEN child.[Count] > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILD_PRG,
  CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE
FROM
  CES_ANAGRAFICA CA
LEFT OUTER JOIN CES_PERMESSI CP
  ON ((CA.ID_CESPITE = CP.ID_CESPITE))
INNER JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE CTCS
  ON CA.ID_TIPO_CESPITE = CTCS.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR
LEFT OUTER JOIN V_UTENTI_DIPENDENTI VUD
  ON CA.ID_RESPONSABILE = VUD.ID_DIPENDENTE
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*)
  FROM V_CESPITE_TREE VCA
  JOIN MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO
    ON MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD
  WHERE VCA.ID_PARENT = CA.ID_CESPITE
    AND MPO.ID_FATHER is not null
) child
```

This should perform slightly better since it doesn't have to perform an aggregate function.

```
SELECT
  CA.ID_CESPITE,
  CASE WHEN child.[Exists] = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILD_PRG,
  CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE
FROM
  CES_ANAGRAFICA CA
LEFT OUTER JOIN CES_PERMESSI CP
  ON ((CA.ID_CESPITE = CP.ID_CESPITE))
INNER JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE CTCS
  ON CA.ID_TIPO_CESPITE = CTCS.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR
LEFT OUTER JOIN V_UTENTI_DIPENDENTI VUD
  ON CA.ID_RESPONSABILE = VUD.ID_DIPENDENTE
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) 1 [Exists]
  FROM V_CESPITE_TREE VCA
  JOIN MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO
    ON MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD
  WHERE VCA.ID_PARENT = CA.ID_CESPITE
    AND MPO.ID_FATHER is not null
) child
```

Comment: May be it would work, by `CROSS JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` terrifies me from further reading... As data volume grows, amount of calculations will grow exponentially.

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECTLY WITH 4500 RECORDS (considering this is a reallife  upper limit for me). I don't award the bounty to you even if you deserve it  since  David Khaykin helped me a lot more. Thanks.

Comment: @user193655 Could you let me know if the second query performs better?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might be a little easier for the optimizer to handle.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID_NODE,
  CASE WHEN MTSub.ID_CHILD is null then 'N' else 'Y' END,
 OTHERFIELDS
FROM MYTABLE2
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT MV.ID_CHILD FROM MYVIEW MV INNER JOIN MYTABLE1 MT1 ON MT1.ID_NODE = MV.ID_CHILD WHERE MV.ID_PARENT = MT2.ID_NODE AND MT1.ID_FATHER IS NOT NULL) MTSub
```

Comment: You're missing the join predicate for your LEFT JOIN